# MySQL -> MariaDB Replication throws Collation Error

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, amazon-rds, master-slave-replication

We are moving from MySQL on AWS RDS to MariaDB on-premise. To do so without downtime, we planned to create a replication first between the MySQL master and the MariaDB slave and then promote the MariaDB slave to become the new master.

MySQL on AWS RDS is 8.0.28
MariaDB on our servers is 10.6

The default MySQL collation is `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`, which MariaDB does not support. So we did:

1. We converted all tables to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` (some were `utf8_unicode_ci`, we kept them that way)
2. Via AWS Parameter Store, we changed the variables `collation_connection`, `collation_server`, `default_collation_for_utf8mb4` to `utf8mb4_general_ci`. These changes are reflected when running `show global VARIABLES like '%collat%'`

Only `collation_database` remains `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`, AWS doesn't allow to modify it.

Importing the dump from MySQL to MariaDB is running without any issues.

But once we start the replication, it immediately fails with

```
Error ‘Character set ‘#255’ is not a compiled character set and is not specified in the ‘/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml’ file’ on query. Default database: ‘’. Query: ‘BEGIN’
```

How can we make this replication work?

Thank you very much

Comment: @danblack - Anything in the works for this issue?

Comment: I can't see any [outstanding feature request](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/#replication-compatibility) for this. I don't have a good grasp as to how different the MySQL-8.0 protocol is compared to what MariaDB can read. The [docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/#replication-compatibility) simply list incompatible.  A MariaDB-10.10+ (with added UCA-14.0.0) collations probably can handle the UCA-9.0.0 collations of MariaDB more accurately. You could start by creating [a task](https://jira.mariadb.org), but its a large body of work.